# ParseException on trying to convert date to milliseconds

Tags: java, swing, datetime, formatting

I am getting `ParseException` when following piece of code is executed:

```
double toMilliseconds(double ds2) throws ParseException
{
    long durinsec;
    DateFormat formatter;
    Date convertedDate;
    String d2 = String.valueOf(ds2);
    System.out.println(d2+"string date");
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmSS");
    convertedDate = formatter.parse(d2);
    System.out.println(convertedDate+"convertedDate");
    durinsec = convertedDate.getTime()/1000;
    System.out.println("Date from yyyyMMdd String in Java : " +durinsec ); 
    return durinsec;    
}
```

Please help on what's wrong. I am getting input from the Java Text Field in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format.

Comment: What data does `ds2` contain?

Comment: ds2 contains input like "20141029090910" in yyyyMMddHHmmss format

Comment: If you are getting the input from a `JTextField`, why would you have converted the input to a double in the first place ? A `JTextField` returns a `String` in the `getText` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of debug your code to find the problem I'd suggest you another approach that will save you all the dirty work: use either [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) to get the input from the users.

You can define the pattern as you wish (i.e.: `yyyyMMddHHmmss`), get the value in a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and use [getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) directly on this date with a tiny effort.

For example:

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
textField.setValue(new Date());

JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

---

#### Edit

If 20141029090910 is a double then `String.valueOf(20141029090910d)` will return something like this:

```
 2.014102909091E13
```

This will cause a parse exception because it doesn't match your pattern.

Comment: ok. But how do i convert it to seconds and store it in a double variable If i Use JSpinner.

Comment: `durinsec = ((Date)spinner.getValue()).getTime() / 1000` ? Please read the tutorials I've linked. @user3857726

Answer (score 2):

I thing that the fundamental problem is your use of a `double` to represent a timestamp.  It is bound to cause problems, especially if you use a funny numeric encoding like that ...

When you do this:

```
  String d2 = String.valueOf(ds2);
```

you encode the number in decimal floating-point format, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-).  In almost all cases, the string resulting from that conversion is going to contain a decimal point; i.e. a ".".  A number string with a decimal point does not match your date format.

The second problem is that your encoding as a `double` doesn't make *mathematical* sense.  For example, if you encoded two dates as `double` values (using your technique) and then subtracted one from the other, the result would be nonsensical.  Certainly, it would not make sense as a duration.

(There is almost a 3rd problem ... except that `double` has just enough precision to represent your numbers.  You need 14 decimal digits, and `double` gives you 15.97.)

---

I recommend that you stop representing dates as `doubles` like this.  If you do want to represent them as numbers, use the standard convention; i.e. an integer number of seconds (or milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, etc) before or after some "epoch".  Better still, use "milliseconds from 1970-01-01-00:00.000" ... which is what the Java libraries use.